# Laravel pagination table - sort for one column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, sorting

I currently have the following:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th> Artikelbild </th>
        <th> Artikelnummer </th>
        <th> Name des Artikels </th>
        <th> Beschreibung </th>
        <th> Preis </th>
        <th> Kategorie </th>
    </tr> @foreach($products as $product)
    <tr class='clickable-row' <?php if($product->stockCount === 0) echo "style='color:red;'";?>data-href="{{url('/product')}}
        <?php echo '/'.$product->id;?>">
        <td> <img src="/images/{{$product->imageUrl}}" class="productImageSmall" /> </td>
        <td> {{$product->id}} </td>
        <td> {{$product->name}} </td>
        <td>
            <?php if (strlen($product->description) > 30) { $productShortened = substr($product->description, 0, 30) . "[...]"; } else { $productShortened = $product->description; } echo $productShortened; ?> </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo number_format($product->price, 2, ',', '.');?>€ </td>
        <td> {{$product->categoryName}} </td>
    </tr> @endforeach
</table>
```

The `$product` thing is passed from my controller with the `paginate()` option.

Now I want that this table is sort-able by one column. So lets say, the user clicks on the "price" (or Preis in german) column on top of the table, then all results should be sorted by the price (from low to high or from high to low), same for the category, for the name and every other column.

How can I do this? Do I have to reload the page and get the data again from the db, but somehow sorted (if yes, how?). Or can I somehow just sort it without reloading it? How can I do this?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Building sortable tables is a pretty time-consuming task, so I'd recommend you to use some package. I use [this package](https://github.com/boxfrommars/rutorika-sortable) for building sortable tables.

If you still want to build this functionality by yourself, you can add arguments like `?price=desc` to the URL and get these with the `request()` method. Just an example:

```
if (request()->has('price')) {
    $query = $query->orderBy('price', request('price'));
}
```

And don't forget to [append URL arguments to the pagination links](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination#displaying-pagination-results):

```
{{ $products->appends(['price' => 'desc'])->render() }}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It looks like with the package you provided I can do something like $products::sorted()->paginate(), right? But does it also provide the functionality to just click on the column to order it by that column or how can I achieve this?

Comment: @nameless yes you can do this and yes, it provides the functionality you described out of the box. It's a really cool package, give it a try.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the hard delay, I had so much to do. It seems like the package is different to what I want. I don't want a sortable table, but a table that automatically sorts depending on a special column, for example I click on the name and then the table is sorted by names (from a-z), I click on the price and the table is sorted by the price (from low to high or the other way), you know what I mean?

Comment: @nameless that is exactly what this package does.

Comment: Ok, then it seems like this is not provided in the demo there? Can you give me an example of how to implement the functionality then?

Comment: @nameless I've used it in admin panels only to display products, users etc. with dynamic sorting feature. So, I'll not be able to show you a demo, sorry.